# Test if postfix is running

Tags: linux, bash, postfix

I'm searching for a reliable way to test if `postfix` is running from inside a bash script.

My first attempt was simply trying `pidof postfix`, which doesn't work.

Then I tried to get the `postfix status`:

```
POSTFIX_LOCATION=/var/packages/MailServer/target/sbin/postfix # location of postfix
result=`$POSTFIX_LOCATION status`
if [ -z $result ]; then
    echo "Error: No status output from postfix"
elif [[ "$result" == *"is running"* ]]; then
    echo "postfix is running!"
else echo "postfix is not running!"
fi
```

But even though the status is reported to the console, the `result` variable stays empty.
This is the console output:

```
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 11996
Error: No status output from postfix
```

I finally found a way to test if postfix is running by getting the process name of `PID: 11996`, which is "master". So the following *does* work:

```
pidof master
```

But this is not very verbose and I'm not sure if this is a reliable way to test if `postfix` is running.

So my questions are:

- How can I get the output of `postfix status` from inside a bash script? -
  Anything I'm doing wrong there?
- Is there a better *reliable* way to test if `postfix` is running from inside a bash script?

Comment: Possible `status` outputs to `stderr`? Try to add `2>&1` to `status`-command. Also you can use `pgrep postfix`

Comment: I tried `2>&1` but the result stays empty. Sadly `pgrep` is no option because it is not available on the system (a Synology disk station with DSM 5.1).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226699/how-to-monitor-postfix-mta-status help?

Comment: `ps aux | grep [p]ostfix` ?

Comment: Thanks @Costas and @garethTheRed - using `ps` seems to work. On the DSM system `ps` doesn't accept any parameters other then `w`. But simply calling `ps | grep [p]ostfix` does work.

Comment: Maybe by getting the status from /ezc/init

Answer (score 19):

Debian or Ubuntu

```
sudo service postfix status
```

Comment: Sorry I though it was fro terminal

Answer (score 4):

A reliable way to test if postfix is running:

```
if /var/packages/MailServer/target/sbin/postfix status; then
    echo "postfix is running!"
else echo "postfix is not running!"
fi
```

An alternative that essentially does the same:

```
if /var/packages/MailServer/target/libexec/master -t 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "postfix is not running!"
else echo "postfix is running!"
fi
```

---

**Reasoning**

After doing some more research, it turned out that testing for `ps | grep [p]ostfix` is not reliable at all to verify if postfix is running.

It seems the reason why `/var/packages/MailServer/target/sbin/postfix status` does not output anything useful is, because `postfix` uses the internal `postlog` binary for the output. The relevant code can be found in the bash script `/var/packages/MailServer/target/libexec/postfix-script`:

```
LOGGER="$command_directory/postlog -t $MAIL_LOGTAG/postfix-script"
INFO="$LOGGER -p info"
```

Checking for the *exit code* of `postfix status` does work fine on the other hand. The `postfix-script` is actually called behind the scenes by the `postfix` binary and cannot be called directly. But luckily the script also includes the code to test if `postfix` is running:

```
status)
    $daemon_directory/master -t 2>/dev/null && {
        $INFO the Postfix mail system is not running
        exit 1
    }
    $INFO the Postfix mail system is running: PID: `sed 1q pid/master.pid`
    exit 0
    ;;
```

The variable `$daemon_directory` gets set by the calling `postfix` binary. On my system it resolves to `/var/packages/MailServer/target/libexec/`.

Comment: `After doing some more research ` Could you support your claims by providing evidence?

Answer (score 4):

To check whether Postfix is running or not:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix status
```

To start the Postfix:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start
```

To stop the postfix:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix stop
```

Comment: I can type `postfix start` without an error message, but when I type `postfix status` it says "the Postfix mail system is not running." I suppose it's silently failing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `is-active` command:

```
if (systemctl is-active -q postfix); then
  echo "Success: postfix is running."
else
  echo "Error: postfix is not running!"
fi
```

Here's the [documentation for 'is-active'](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-active%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running postfix inside a very lean docker container and has very few normal commands installed. Yet it does have netstat.  So use netstat to list ports that a process is listening on.  Look for a process listening on the smtp port (e.g. postfix).

```
if ! netstat -l | grep smtp; then
    echo "postfix is not running!"
else echo "postfix is running!"
fi
```

Comment: Can't you just do `if postfix status; then echo running; fi`? You shouldn't need any other command than `postfix` here as `postfix` itself can tell its own service status.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas is correct and all the other dances are not needed.  Thanks Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

I believe the suggested solutions with "master -t" and "postfix status" may incorrectly report that postfix is running if it was previously killed forcibly leaving its PID files behind.

"pidof master" and similar ps/grep manipulations are fine, except there might be other processes called "master".

So "sudo service postfix status" might be the best (except OP is running DSM where this is not applicable).